# Deployment of SQL compact Edition (SDF files) using Setup project

Tags: deployment, sql-server-ce, setup-project

I have a C#.NET desktop application using SQL Compact edition as data store.
The application should be used by any user on the machine and all should be seeing the same data ( data should not different per user).

I am wondering where should I deploy the SDF file?

- User's Personal data folder (My Documents) means each user will have a separate database.
- Deploying on the same folder as the application causes vista to copy the file to \USers\Appdata\local\VirtualStore\ and it seems to make different copies for each user.

Where is it best to deploy the SDF file to ensure all users are looking at the same data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deploy to a location under the %ProgramData% folder, it can be accessed by all users of the machine